# WP_Query with many-to-many relationship field not returning results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a custom wordpress query that uses a relationship field called "related_places" to connect posts to multiple places (a custom post type). If there is only one connected place in the relationship field my code works. If I add multiple connected places, the results will disappear entirely if I just use get_field. If I put the places in an array the results still show, but it only returns the first place listed in the field. And if I use the ID field, its returns places whether or not they are connected. I cant find the middle ground where all related places show and all non-related places dont. Can anyone see what I am missing?

```
function related_places(){
    $rplace = get_field( 'related_places',false,false ); 
    /*If I use $rplace in the WP_query, the results disapear entirely if there is more than one related "place". 
    It works if there is only one connection)*/
    $rplace_array = $rplace[0];
    $rplace_ID = $rplace_array->ID; /*returns all places whether or not they are connected, there is no filter*/


    $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type'         => 'gd_place',
      'posts_per_page'    => 6,
      'post__in' => $rplace_array, /*only the first related record is returned using this*/
      'orderby'=> 'post__in'
      ));

    if($query->have_posts()) :

            while($query->have_posts()) :

                $query->the_post() ;

            $result .= '<div class="place-item">';
            $result .= '<div class="place-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</div>';
            $result .= '<div class="place-name">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
            $result .= '</div>';

            endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;    

        return $result;       
}
```

I am not sure if its relevant, but the relationship field was created with the "PODS" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PODS, it is not necessary to use WP_Query to get field values. According to [the documentation](https://docs.pods.io/tutorials/get-values-from-a-relationship-field/), you can read all the IDs directly from the POD using the name that you have created

```
<?php 
    function related_places(){
        //get Pods object for current post
        //Replace pod_name with your pod name
        $pod = pods( 'pod_name', get_the_id() );
        //get the value for the relationship field
        $related = $pod->field( 'related_places' );
        //loop through related field, creating links to their own pages
        //only if there is anything to loop through
        $result = '';
        if ( ! empty( $related ) ) {
            foreach ( $related as $rel ) { 
                //get id for related post and put in ID
                //for advanced content types use $id = $rel[ 'id' ]
                $id = $rel[ 'ID' ];
                $result .= '<div class="place-item">';
                $result .= '<div class="place-image">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $id ) . '</div>';
                $result .= '<div class="place-name">' . get_the_title( $id ) . '</div>';
                $result .= '</div>';
            } //end of foreach

        } //endif ! empty ( $related )
        return $result;
    }
?>
```